# Undefined reference to get_mysql_instance

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql-connector

I'm writing a code in C++ with MySQL Cpp Conn 6.1 to connect to a database and write data for later use. When trying to initialize the driver with driver = get_driver_instance(); it returns an error message:

```
Creating executable: out/gcc-debug//DB8.exe
out/gcc-debug//defaultSensor.o: In function `Z10dbWriteWiniiiii':
C:\Users\LuisH.Forchesatto\Dropbox\ProjetosOmnet++\DB8/dbWriteWin.h:35: undefined reference to `_imp___ZN3sql5mysql19get_driver_instanceEv'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:85: recipe for target 'out/gcc-debug//DB8.exe' failed
make: *** [out/gcc-debug//DB8.exe] Error 1
```

I tried to add mysqlcppconn to the link option (-lmysqlcppconn) but it returns the following error message:

```
Creating executable: out/gcc-debug//DB8.exe
C:\Users\LuisH.Forchesatto\Downloads\omnetpp-4.6\tools\win32\mingw32\bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmysqlcppconn
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:85: recipe for target 'out/gcc-debug//DB8.exe' failed
make: *** [out/gcc-debug//DB8.exe] Error 1
```

- this error applies if I include the full path to mysqlcppconn.dll or .lib as well as including their directories to paths and symbols.

The non initialized driver variable may be causing crashes when trying to connect to the database so it needs to work.

The paths and symbols contains the includes for mysqlcppconn headers and boost library headers. The full code to the application is in the link below.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85576999/dbWriteWin.h

Answer (score 0):

2 possible error causes,
I  - you are refering to undeclered function or variable
II - you aren´t including the proper library in compilation time

Comment: Please, could you elaborate? What library could be missing? What function needs to be declared? I tried this a lot already and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Update: I read that I needed -lmysqlcppconn and -lmysqlcppconn-static to work with get driver instance. However, when I try to add these I get the following error message:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/85576999/error.txt
(yes, it's a long error message)